# Google Drive Android API Authentication Problems

Tags: java, android, token, drive

I'm working on an app that creates / updates a single text file in its private app data folder in Google. This is done with the REST v3 Drive API. 
It was working very well several days ago and now it doesn't. The only thing that changed as far as I know is that I uploaded it to Google Play. I'm
having trouble with my app connecting to the app, as the `service` variable is returning null. My thoughts are that maybe I need a refresh token or something but I haven't been able to find anything on how to do that with the v3 API.
I would GREATLY appreciate some help with this.

Here's what I've tried so far:
1. Created a new keystore and re-downloaded the google-services.json file with the new sha1 fingerprint
2. Disabled and re-enabled the Drive API
3. I develop my project on 'release' variant, probably bad but it was working before
4. Banging my head against the wall

Here's the source code:

```
// Gather credentials
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES)).setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Roblu", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String accountName = settings.getString("accountName", "");
credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);

// Start Google services
HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();

JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
// This is returning null
service = new Drive.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("Roblu").build();
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
```

**EDIT**
This line is returning null for the `Drive` object. Ideas?

```
service = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("Roblu").build();
```

Comment: Does the SHA1 fingerprint come from the same keystore that you used to sign your published app?

Comment: No..... my app is published under a different keystore, but I'm running the app over adb with a different keystore -- is that a problem? @x-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you publish an app that uses a Google service like the Drive REST API, you need to add a credential for the production version of the app, with a SHA1 fingerprint derived from the same keystore that you used to sign the APK.

Typically during testing you add a credential that is derived from the debug keystore. This credential will *not* work with the production version of the app.

So you go to the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) and add a new credential.